# Slideshow dinamico con php y AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

estoy creando un sistema de galería con slideshow para productos, la idea es que cada producto cargue su slider recogiendo fotos desde la base de datos, el tema es el siguiente, cuando introduzco manual funciona todo perfecto pero por alguna extraña razón cuando cargo o monto una imagen vía ajax o servidor, no pasa nada, no funciona y la verdad que no logro ver la razón de porque pasa esto si el código esta bien.

```html
        <div id="upload_photo" data-u="slides" style="cursor:default;position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;width:980px;height:380px;overflow:hidden;">
            <div data-p="170.00">
                <img data-u="image" src="img/adorable-21998_640.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div data-p="170.00">
                <img data-u="image" src="img/adorable-21998_640.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Esto es la imagen dentro del slider, si lo coloco asi funciona perfecto y anda todo perfecto, pero cuando lo cargo via ajax, no funciona
ACÁ el código Javascript

```js
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
              url:'http://www.ebabylist.es/appstore/extra/view/load_product_gallery.php'+window.location.search+'&type=slider',
              method:'GET',
              cache:false,
              success:function(fancyBox){
                  $("#upload_photo").append(fancyBox);
                  
              },
              error:function(err_fancy){
                  console.log(err_fancy);
                  alert("No se puede cargar la galeria en este momento");
              }
           }); 
        });
    </script>
```

Finalmente el codigo PHP que recoge  y devuelve de la bbdd

```js
private function slideshow($prod_slider){
        $statement = "SELECT * FROM galeria WHERE producto_id = :producto";
        try{
            $msg = $this->BBDD->prepare($statement);
            $msg->bindValue(":producto", htmlentities(addslashes($prod_slider)));
            $msg->execute();
            if($msg->rowCount()!=0){
               foreach($msg->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $fancy){
                  echo "                                    
                       <div data-p='170.00'>
                        <img data-u='image' src='http://www.ebabylist.es/appstore/img/{$fancy->foto_nombre}' />
                       </div>                     
                        ";
               }
            }
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            die('Fail to read this message' . $ex->getLine() . PHP_EOL . $ex->getCode() . ' ' . PHP_EOL. $ex->getMessage());
        }finally{
            $this->BBDD = NULL;
        } 
    }
```

Si coloco los div manual como se ve al principio, funciona pero a cargarlo dinamicamente, me genera los mismos div e items pero no funciona, alguna idea porque?

Answer (score 0):

Debes enviar solo la URL de la imagen desde el PHP. El HTML lo construyes desde el JavaScript.

Ejemplo:

```
//aqui tienes el $each que recorre el objeto

var HTML = "";

HTML += < img scr='URL'>;

//fin each


$("#upload_photo").html(HTML);
```

y luego cuando creas el slider generalmente tiene un método que se llama `.refresh();` que es para refrescar el contenido dinámico desde jQuery.

Comment: Hola @Simon. Bienvenido a [es.so] y gracias por tu aporte... Creo que sería recomendable que al publicar el código, sea un código que pueda ejecutarse. Por ejemplo, estás asignando a `HTML` algo que parece un string, pero no está entre comillas.. Y no estás mostrando cómo concatenaría el valor. La idea del sitio es sumar contenido con la mayor calidad posible. ¿Crees que podrías aceitar un poco el ejemplo? ¿Quizás dando un poco más de contexto en la implementación y el motivo por el cual tiene que hacerlo así?